# Comparing values in MySQL table based on another tables rows

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, comparison

I am working on an application system in CakePHP. Each application contains the address and a (UK only) postcode of the applicant.

The client wants to be able to assign "postcode areas" to a given member of their team.
Unfortunately the postcode area varies in format and length - examples: `TA`, `TQ1`, `S60`, `BS22`, `TA6 4EJ`

The user wants to be able to specify entire areas, or more specific areas on a per user basis if required.
[image: schema]

I need to be able to take each `prefix` and compare it to the `postcode` for each application, and return any matches.

---

User `Ross` manages applications with postcode beginning with: `BQ`. `BS` and `S60`

User `Dave` manages applications with full postcodes: `BS22 4JL` and `TA6 7EJ`

---

I figured that the best way would be to have a table full of user-defined postcode prefixes:

```
   id  |  prefix
    1  |      TQ
    2  |      TL
    3  |     S50
    4  |     S55
    5  | TA6 4EJ
```

Each user is assigned a postcode area to manage.

I'm thinking if I can compare each application postcode to each prefix, I can retrieve all applications in a given postcode area, then look up the user that this belongs.

```
id | postcode
1  |  tq33 abc
2  |  TL5  8HA
3  |  s50 11l
```

The postcode data isn't in any standard/regular format unfortunately; so this might get tricky.
It sounds like I need to `JOIN` the `prefix` on to the postcode; but as there's no key I don't think that's possible.

There's no direct association between `prefix` and `postcode`. Feel like I'm missing something fundamental

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT users.name, app.* from applications app, users, postcodes where app.postcode LIKE CONCAT(postcodes.prefix,'%') AND postcodes.user_id = users.id
```